# Nox App Player error, cannot get it to run

Tags: wine, emulation, android-emulator

I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and am attempting to run an easy, good emulator. One such emulator is Nox App Player. It has installed successfully, I can get it to boot up, but it doesn't successfully do so. With wine set to Windows XP it gives this error after progressing up to a point, usually around 76% (I have also downloaded a supposed error fix patch to fix this. That isn't working well):

> Virtual machine error, restart Nox to repair or contact customer help!(Initialize Emulator components Failed!)

As for having it set to Windows 7, this error is given, and it won't even start:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform program "windows".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

(Doing so, to no surprise, did not work. At all. I can't install under 7)

If further information is needed, ask and you shall receive. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nox requires *Virtualization* to be enabled in your *BIOS*. I'm not sure if this has something to do with your issue but it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run an emulator in an emulator. That usually doesn't work well. Unfortunately, at this time, GenyMotion is your best option. If you're wanting to run games, then unfortunately, there isn't much out there for Linux. WineHQ lists Nox App Player as "garbage" at this time and that was v3.7.x.x. The latest Nox is v3.8.0.5 and it still doesn't run under Wine. Again, running an emulator in an emulator is just asking for trouble anyways, especially when you're trying to virtualize the hardware.

Comment: Wine Is Not Emulator :)